# Already value [datasource.ConnectionHolder@6b144bd8] for key [datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@56739ee9] bound to thread [main]

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, datasource, spring-transactions

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@6b144bd8] for key [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@56739ee9] bound to thread [main]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:446)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:378)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy260.getTransaction(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:474)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:289)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy229.findById(Unknown Source)
at com.medical.healthcarems.service.PathwayService.createBatchPathwayInvitation(PathwayService.java:138)
at com.medical.healthcarems.service.PathwayService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b1c67fd5.invoke()
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
at com.medical.healthcarems.service.PathwayService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d2800755.createBatchPathwayInvitation()
at com.medical.healthcarems.config.batch2.PersonItemProcessor.process(PersonItemProcessor.java:72)
at com.medical.healthcarems.config.batch2.PersonItemProcessor.process(PersonItemProcessor.java:22)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:129)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.transform(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:306)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:205)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273)
at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:203)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:399)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:313)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:144)
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:137)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy239.run(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:214)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:186)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:172)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:166)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:813)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:797)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:324)
at com.medical.healthcarems.HealthcareMsApplication.main(HealthcareMsApplication.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@6b144bd8] for key [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@56739ee9] bound to thread [main]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:193)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:421)
... 80 common frames omitted

I got this problem while trying to implement spring batch job :

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource batchDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/medical_db_local");
        dataSource.setSchema("healthcare");
        dataSource.setUsername("healthcare_ms_local");
        dataSource.setPassword("secret");
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TransactionManagerConfig {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource batchDataSource;

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager batchTransactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(batchDataSource);
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration  {
    public static final String COLUMN_DELIMITER = ";";
    @Value("${application.batch.chunkSize}")
    private Integer chunkSize;
    @Autowired
    private DataSource batchDataSource;
    @Autowired
    private DataSourceTransactionManager batchTransactionManager;



    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository() throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(batchDataSource);
        factory.setTransactionManager(batchTransactionManager);
        factory.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ");
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<InvitationRequest> reader() {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<InvitationRequest>()
                .name("invitationItemReader")
                .resource(new ClassPathResource("file_name"))
                .delimited()
                .delimiter(";")
                .names({col1, col2, col3})
                .targetType(InvitationRequest.class)
                .strict(false)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PersonItemProcessor processor() {
        return new PersonItemProcessor();
    }


    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<InvitationRequest> writer(DataSource batchDataSource) {
        return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<InvitationRequest>()
                .sql("INSERT INTO notification_request (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (:col1, :col2, :col3)")
                .dataSource(batchDataSource)
                .beanMapped()
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public Job importUserJob(JobRepository jobRepository, Step step1, JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) {
        return new JobBuilder("importUserJob")
                .repository(jobRepository)
                .listener(listener)
                .start(step1)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(JobRepository jobRepository, DataSourceTransactionManager batchTransactionManager,
                      FlatFileItemReader<InvitationRequest> reader, PersonItemProcessor processor,
                      JdbcBatchItemWriter<InvitationRequest> writer) {
        return new StepBuilder("step1")
                .repository(jobRepository)
                .transactionManager(batchTransactionManager)
                .<InvitationRequest, InvitationRequest> chunk(2)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
        asyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(10);
        return asyncTaskExecutor;
    }

}
```

I think the problem is the presence of twi datasource beans on the same thread !
but when don't configure a bean datasource to the batch job ! I got error of no such bean !
and when I configure it I have two beans in the thread ! what can be the solution please ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.